# PHP/MySQL Image array title change

Tags: php

If I've got some php code, below:

```
while($galleryResult=mysql_fetch_array($galleryQuery)) {                              
                echo '<li><img src="../../images/properties/gallery/'.$galleryResult['imagename'].'" width="120" height="120" class="image" /><br />                                                 
                      <input type="text" style="width:120px;" name="newGalleryTitle" value="'.$galleryResult['galleryTitle'].'"><br />
                      <label for="updateTitle'.$galleryResult['id'].'"><input id="updateTitle'.$galleryResult['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="title_ids[]" value="'.$galleryResult['id'].'" /> Update title?</label><br />
                      </li>    
                '. PHP_EOL;                        
            }
```

Which outputs this html, below;

```
<li><img src="../../images/properties/gallery/image-name.jpg" width="120" height="120" class="image" /><br />                        
<input type="text" style="width:120px;" name="newGalleryTitle" value="Test No2"><br />
<label for="updateTitle1"><input id="updateTitle1" type="checkbox" name="title_ids[]" value="1" /> Update title?</label><br /></li>    

<li><img src="../../images/properties/gallery/image-name-02-jpg.jpg" width="120" height="120" class="image" /><br />                        
<input type="text" style="width:120px;" name="newGalleryTitle" value="Test No2"><br />
<label for="updateTitle2"><input id="updateTitle2" type="checkbox" name="title_ids[]" value="2" /> Update title?</label><br /></li>
```

etc etc.

And this is the code I'm using to try and update the image 'titles', below:

```
if (!empty($_POST['title_ids'])) {  
        foreach ($_POST['title_ids'] as $titleId) {                    
            $error=$_POST['newGalleryTitle'];
            $gtsql=mysql_query("UPDATE isgallery SET galleryTitle = '".$_POST['newGalleryTitle']."' WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($titleId));                
              mysql_query($gtsql);                
         }
    }
```

Now, this all works great if I select the last image in the array, but if I choose any other or multiple images, it will take the image title from the last image and write it into the selected image title.

My question is: How do I go about 'grabbing' the correct image title? I know it's selecting the correct item/image in the array, just not the image title.

Hope this makes sense and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, S

Comment: you need to remove this mysql_query($gtsql); (double query!) - and please show me the print_r($_POST['title_ids']);

Comment: I think he had the second query accidentally there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your

```
while($galleryResult=mysql_fetch_array($galleryQuery)) {                              
    echo '<li><img src="../../images/properties/gallery/'.$galleryResult['imagename'].'" width="120" height="120" class="image" /><br />                                                 
        <input type="text" style="width:120px;" name="newGalleryTitle"
```

with this:

```
while($galleryResult=mysql_fetch_array($galleryQuery)) {                              
    echo '<li><img src="../../images/properties/gallery/'.$galleryResult['imagename'].'" width="120" height="120" class="image" />';
    echo '<input type="text" style="width:120px;" name="newGalleryTitle['. $galleryResult['id'] .']" value="'.$galleryResult['galleryTitle'].'">';
    echo '<label for="updateTitle'.$galleryResult['id'].'"><input id="updateTitle'.$galleryResult['id'].'" type="checkbox" name="title_ids[]" value="'.$galleryResult['id'].'" /> Update title?</label>';
    echo '</li>'. PHP_EOL;
}
```

And then, when you process your data just access the needed values like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['title_ids'] as $titleId) {                    
            $error=$_POST['newGalleryTitle'][$titleId];
```

And yes - remove the second mysql_query from your loop since you already have it once.